# Getting the "empApi setting initialized true for : undefined" log in JS console?

Tags: lightning-web-components, platform-event, empapi

I have one **LWC**, where I subscribe to Platform Events using  [lightning/empApi](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation) .

Here the JS code from the LWC :

```javascript
    import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
    import { subscribe, onError} from 'lightning/empApi';
    
    export default class PlatformEventOrderSubscriber extends LightningElement {
        channelName = '/event/Event_Type__e';
        subscription = {};

        connectedCallback() {
            this.registerErrorListener();
            this.handleSubscribe();
    }

        handleSubscribe() {
            subscribe(this.channelName, -1, (response) => this.messageCallbackProcessor(response)).then(response => {
                this.subscription = response;
            }).catch(error=>{
            console.error(error);
            });
        }
    
        messageCallbackProcessor(response) {
            // do sommething
        }

        registerErrorListener() {
            onError(error => {
                console.log('Received error from server: ', JSON.stringify(error));
            });
        }
    }
```

And I currently noticed that I started getting the next log in Browser Console :

> `empApi setting initialized true for : undefined`

The log in my Browser console :

[image]

**It did NOT cause any issues for me.**

However **I want to know**. **Should I be aware of it?**

I couldn't find anything about it in the documentation !

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: This is an [X-Y Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). You're asking about a Y, but we don't know the X. At minimum, we need to know if this error is causing any problems, if this is your own code, etc. Without details, it'd be hard to answer. Can you please [edit] your question to include more information?

Comment: @sfdcfox I updated the question with detail information about it.

Answer (score 1):

*[Edit for clarity] This could be related to the following Salesforce known issue:*
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000002C10xQAC